# addSubview displays black screen with no content - iPhone

Tags: objective-c, uiview, nsbundle, addsubview

When I load my xib: AboutViewController as a subview of the view contentView, I just get a blank black screen, can someone help??

```
UIView* moreView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AboutViewController" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

    [_revealView.contentView addSubview:moreView];
```

Comment: Using `lastObject` to access something inside the XIB makes your code harder to understand.  I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but your code would be easier to understand if you connected the view to an outlet on the file's owner instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use view controllers instead, then just access the view of the view controller:

```
UIViewController * aboutVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];
[_revealView.contentView addSubview:aboutVC.view];
```

Alternatively, you may be interested in presenting the view modally:

```
[_revealView.contentView.viewController presentModalViewController:aboutVC
                                                          animated:(BOOL)animated];
```

If you are not using ARC, you will have to manage `aboutVC` manually with retain and release.